# On delete method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a method which passes ownership of a piece of information to a parent user when they are deleted, but I currently invoke this prior to @user.destroy in the controller.

Is there any way to run a method on delete by convention rather than how I am currently doing it? Something like `on_delete: :do_this_method` in the model, is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
  before_destroy :do_this_method
```

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Sidenote: I recommend you always use `destroy` instead of `delete`.